# I want to send an enter command through a bash file, to run a bin file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i am new to scripting, i am running an bin file through a bash command, and once the bin starts to run its expects an enter key to continue. Below is the script

```
#!/bin/bash
pwd; cd /root/program;
pwd;
echo start install
echo !@#$%^
sleep 10;
sh program.bin;
```

once the bin starts to execute it expects an enter. Can any one please guide me.

Comment: Depending on how the binary reads the input you can pipe `echo` with your binary or you will have to use more heavy weapon like `expect`. First, try this: `echo Yes | ./program.bin`

Comment: What does the script `program.bin` look like?

Comment: For automating interactive console applications, keep in mind the [`expect`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).

Comment: Please comment on the provided solutions @user2470170, so that it can be improved further!

Answer (score 0):

For triggering a keypress using bash, take a look at xdotool. You can get it using apt-get install xdotool and its documentation is found here (http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml). The text to trigger an enter keystroke is KP_ENTER.